# Toral subgroup acting regularly on the homogeneous space

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected second countable compact Hausdorff group, and let $H\subset G$ be a closed subgroup such that the homogeneous space $G/H$ has continuum cardinality. For every $x\in G/H$ let $H_x\subset G$ be the stability subgroup at $x$.

**Question:** Does there exist a toral subgroup $\mathbb{T}\subset G$ such that the subset $\{x\in G/H\,|\quad\mathbb{T}\cap H_x\neq\{1\}\}$ is at most countable?

Here $\mathbb{T}\subset G$ is a closed subgroup isomorphic to the usual torus $U(1)$.

This may turn out to be a very easy question, I just can't figure out an efficient approach. Thank you.

Comment: Some questions : what do you mean by toral subgroup ? abelian connected subgroup ? compact ? The intersection $T\cap H_x$ contains the neutral element, you may not want to require the intersection to be empty ?

Comment: Yes, what is "a toral subgroup"? Note: The Pontryagin dual of the rationals doesn't have any subgroup isomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Rationals with which topology? Discrete? Is the dual connected in that case? Note that I explicitly required $G$ to be connected. Every pro-torus in a connected compact group is a projective limit of finite dimensional tori, and in particular contain a 1-torus.

Comment: Let $G$ be the  [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)) and $H=\{1\}$. Then $G$ contains no total subgroups.

Comment: I just realized Uri Bader mentioned the same example since the solenoid is isomorphic to the Pontryagin dual of the additive group of rational numbers (with the standard topology).

Comment: Consider a discrete abelain group $G$. Exercises: 1) $\hat{G}$ is connected iff $G$ is torsion free. 2) $\hat{G}$ has a subgroup iso to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ iff $G$ has a quotient iso to $\mathbb{Z}$. Deduce: $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$ is connected with no isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. BTW, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a direct limit of $\mathbb{Z}$'s, thus $\hat{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an inverse limit of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$'s (so it is a solenoid, as Misha mentioned). In particular, you should double check your claim "Every pro-torus... contain a 1-torus".

Comment: A locally compact Abelian group is compact if and only if its Pontrjagin dual is discrete. If you take rational numbers with standard topology (as Misha suggested), then it is not discrete, and hence its Pontrjagin dual is not compact. In order to get a compact dual, you need to take $\mathbb{Q}$ with discrete topology.

Comment: Every element of a compact connected group is contained in a maximal pro-torus (e.g., Hoffman, Morris). A protorus is the projective limit of finite dimensional tori (e.g., Wikipedia: protorus). Whether or not it contains a 1-torus I am not 100% sure in this generality, have to think. Solenoid is a protorus, but I am not sure about its proper subgroups. Solenoid is a weird thing, that's probably why Smale looked so sad when we met last time. I will also go through Uri Bader's excercises and see what it gives. Thanks.

Comment: It's a pleasant exercise to show that (any) solenoid does not contain topological circles (you do not even need to assume they are subgroups).